# printf in Windows x86-64 shellcode, strings on stack, and alignment

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

From x64 shellcode on Windows 10, I want to call `printf("String: %s\n", "Hello World")` with the string `"Hello World"` defined on the stack. I ran into problems that I’ve somewhat fixed, but I understand neither the problem nor my solution. I read that the x64 ABI mandates the stack to be 16-byte aligned before call instructions, but this does not seem to explain all of it.

After some playing around with `nasm`, I arrived at the following code, which works:

```
bits 64
default rel

segment .data
    msg db "String: %s", 0xd, 0xa, 0

segment .text
global main
extern ExitProcess

extern printf

main:
    push rbp
    mov  rbp, rsp
    sub  rsp, 64  ; relevant number 1

    mov  rdx, rsp
    add  rdx, 32  ; relevant number 2
    mov  dword [rdx],     "Hell"
    mov  dword [rdx + 4], "o Wo"
    mov  dword [rdx + 8], "rld"
    
    lea  rcx, [msg]
    call printf

    xor  rcx, rcx
    call ExitProcess
```

Curiously, there are certain combinations of values for the `rsp` and the position `rdx` of the string on the stack that work and certain combinations that don’t. However, I don’t see the general rule.

| Number 1 | Number 2 | Works? | Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 64 | 0 | no |  |
| 64 | 8 | no | x¨/(☻ |
| 64 | 16 | no | Pf{tè☻ |
| 64 | 24 | no | Ï¨;í |
| 64 | 32 | yes | Hello World |
| 64 | 40 | yes | Hello World |
| 64 | 48 | yes | Hello World |
| 64 | 56 | yes | Hello World |
| 64 | 64 | yes | Hello World |
| 32 | 0 | no |  |
| 32 | 8 | no | °²øRg |
| 32 | 16 | no | ákG×│☺ |
| 32 | 24 | no | ↑°wd¢ |
| 32 | 32 | yes | Hello World |

What’s going on? Why do we need to store the string at least 32 bytes away from the `rsp`? This seem unrelated to the 16-byte alignment requirement.

Comment: Yes you need to store it 32 bytes away and yes that is unrelated to the alignment. It is because of the shadow space which is 32 bytes. Within your block of allocated space (meaning from +32 to +64) you can put the string anywhere since that requires no alignment which should mean the second number does not need to be a multiple of 8.

Comment: @Jester Oh, well, today I learned that *shadow space* exists ;-) I guess I’ll go and read about it. Thank you!